# Powershell to Remove folder that starts with a String that only contains Empty Folders

Tags: powershell, directory

I have a Folder structure that looks something like this:

```
E:\Customers\<customername>\Opportunity<#####>\<Folder-Template>
```

Where `<Folder-Template>` is 15 folders that May or may not have FILES buried in them.

If `E:\Customers\<customername>\Opportunity<#####>` has no FILES in it (just Empty Directories), I want to remove the `Opportunity<#####>` folder.

I started off with this:

```
$foldersList = Get-ChildItem E:\Customers\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}
$foldersList | Where-Object {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0}
```

That got me a list of all of the Empty Folders, but only at that Folder Level and it also included `<customername>` folders if there were no files at that level.  I then tried adding   `-and  $_.Name.StartsWith("Opportunity")` to the `Where-Object`, but that does not tell me if there are files within the 'Folder Template' structure, Just if the Opportunity folder has no Files.

Looking more like I'm going to need a Loop and some flags, but wanted to toss it out there if there was a better way?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
Get-ChildItem E:\Customers\*\Opportunity* |
  Where-Object { ($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force).Count -eq 0} |
  Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- `Get-ChildItem E:\Customers\*\Opportunity*` uses a single [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expression to target all candidate folders.
- `$_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force` recursively finds all files (only) in each candidate folder.